# Unable to upload large file using GCDWebServer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, gcdwebserver

I am trying to upload a large video file using `GCDWebServer` but am unable to upload it. Video with small size is uploaded successfully but problems occur in large video file uploading.

Actually using `GCDWebServer` I am importing files from pc to an iOS device and writing those files in the app document path using the below code. first I am removing web forms data from a file and then write it in to app document path.

```
            let dataRequest = request as? GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest
            var fileData = dataRequest?.data
            
            if let dataString = String(data: fileData!, encoding: .isoLatin1) {
                let split = dataString.components(separatedBy: "\r\n\r\n")
                let splitFirst = split.first?.components(separatedBy: "filename=")
                let splitName = splitFirst![1].components(separatedBy: "\r\n")
                fileName = splitName.first!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
                fileData = split[1].data(using: .isoLatin1)
            } else {
              // getting nil dataString
            }
```

Now when I try to convert a small uploaded file data to a string I get the result in `dataString`, but getting `dataString` `nil` if the file size is large. eg. 500MB

please, someone suggest me an appropriate answer. `GCDWebServer` is a new topic for me.

one more thing [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) mention the below feature, if anyone has an idea about it please let me know.

- Parser for [web forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) submitted using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data" encodings (including file uploads)